# Sendgrid can't receive emails in application

Tags: php, email, nginx, laravel-5

I'm trying to receive e-mails sended to my account on sendgrid.
So What I basically have is the following:

- A sendgrid account linked to http://www.rallypodium.be
- A cloudflare account linked to http://www.rallypodium.be server IP adress.
- A server on [DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/997ee5c5363d).

Good, So I'm running `Nginx` on that server and I want to be able to get the e-mails send to `@rallypodium.be` to be saved and stored inside of my database wich is on the same DigitalOcean server.

I've set up the Inbound Parse like this:

HOST: www.rallypodium.be
URL: http://www.rallypodium.be/inbound/parse/mail

My domain is whitelabled.

I've read the docs for 10 times and still didn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is how I store them:

```
public function ReceiveMail(Request $request)
    {
      DB::table('email')->insert([
          'headers' => $request->get('headers'),
          'html' => $request->get('html'),
          'from' => $request->get('from'),
          'to' => $request->get('to'),
          'cc' => $request->get('cc'),
          'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
          'dkim' => $request->get('dkim'),
          'spf' => $request->get('spf'),
          'envelope' => $request->get('envelope'),
          'charsets' => $request->get('charsets'),
          'spam_score' => $request->get('spam_score'),
          'spam_report' => $request->get('spam_report'),
          'attachments' => $request->get('attachments'),
          'attachment-info' => $request->get('attachment-info'),
          'attachmentX' => $request->get('attachmentX')
      ]);
      return 'ok';
    }
```

If I take a look at the Activity Feed, then I see this:

[image]

The error message is the following:

EMAIL: robin@rallypodium.be

REASON: error dialing remote address: dial tcp 104.24.101.114:25: i/o timeout

SMTP-ID: <1f7f313f27fd051b525581562e6af9b5@rallypodium.be>

PROCESSED STRING: August 1, 2016 - 06:53:45PM

MSGID: J1irmehmR_GELI7tIpPXNg.filter0810p1mdw1.1861.579F77CC27.0

oh and this is my cloudflare DNS: http://prntscr.com/c0bjl8

Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially trying to receive email through CloudFlare, but unfortunately [CloudFlare doesn't proxy SMTP/email traffic](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168876-My-email-or-mail-stopped-working-What-should-I-do-).

Instead you'll need to add a grey-clouded record to manage your email, this will allow your email to be routed straight to your origin without CloudFlare blocking it. Note that grey clouded domains can reveal your IP Address, it is therefore recommended to have your email server on a separate server to your webserver; or even better use a Cloud email provider and get emails from them.

[image: CloudFlare email records]

Comment: Whatever server is receiving the email; in your current set-up this would be your server IP.

Comment: If you looj at my question, I've added the DNS, this is what I have now: http://prntscr.com/c0bppx

Comment: It still doesn't work to receive e-mails after 22 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I experienced the same problem. I then updated my Cloudflare but since it might take 24hrs to propagate, I then used a different domain that is not under Cloudflare. I will see tomorrow if my Cloudflare domain would be working.